# function object with public static properties

Tags: javascript, function, object, static-methods

So I know I can add public properties to functions directly like this.

```js
const print = function (string) {
    console.log(string);
};
print.uppercase = function (string) {
    print(string.toUpperCase());
};

print("apple");            //  apple
print.uppercase("apple");  //  APPLE
```

But I always follow this pattern when I make objects.

```js
const object = function () {
    let field;
    const getField = function () {
        return field;
    };
    const setField = function (_field) {
        field = _field;
    };
    return Object.freeze({
            getField,
            setField
        });
};
```

Is it possible to make function objects with public properties while sticking to this pattern? Without using `this`?

```js
const factory = function () {
    const generic = function () {};
    const specific = function () {};

    return Object.freeze({
        // DO SOMETHING HERE SO THAT
        });
};

// factory() invokes the generic function, and
// factory.specific() invokes the specific function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
generic.specific = specific;
Object.freeze(generic);
return generic;
```

or for short,

```
return Object.freeze(Object.assign(generic, {
  specific,
}));
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I’ve also started to think that maybe I should just make it a module and default export the generic function with specific functions assigned to it.  

```javascript
const generic = function () {};
const specific = function () {};

export default Object.freeze(
        Object.assign(generic, specific)
    );
```  

What do you think? I know I’m now just asking for your personal opinion but I’m still curious if you would recommend doing this

Comment: If you want to write an es6 module, you should just use named exports instead. Much easier to use and understand, and a namespace object is immutable as well (albeit not callable).